# Huge flickering in simple console game in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, console-application

I'm making my first console game in C# which is a simple maze game, but for some reason I have a ridiculous amount of flickering on the screen. I have tried using Thread.Sleep AND Console.CursorVisible=false; but to no avail. 
In case you get stuck press 1 and then enter on the title screen, and that will lead you to the maze which is still in the pre-alpha stage. If it makes a difference I'm using Visual Studio 2013 as an IDE. My question is how can I get rid of the excessive flickering in the maze sections.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;

class Game
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Select Level (Available levels: 1,2):");
        Console.WriteLine("\n(\\_/)\n(o.o)\n(___)0\n");
        int gameLevel = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // by pressing a number the user can select different labyrinths.
        // Console Height and Width
        Console.BufferHeight = Console.WindowHeight = 25;
        Console.BufferWidth = Console.WindowWidth = 80;
        Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;  // Must have this + Change font to Lucida in CMD

        // Reads File:
        string map = File.ReadAllText(String.Format("level{0}.txt", gameLevel));
        string[] mapRows = Regex.Split(map, "\r\n");
        int mapSize = mapRows[0].Length;
        int mapHeight = mapRows.Count() - 1;
        char[,] charMap = new char[mapHeight, mapSize];

        // Creates Matrix:
        for (int row = 0; row < mapHeight; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < mapSize; col++)
            {
                charMap[row, col] = mapRows[row].ElementAt(col);
            }
        }
        // Rabbit init:
        string rabbitIcon = "\u0150";   //  \u0150   \u014E    \u00D2     \u00D3 --> alternatives
        int rabbitX = 1, rabbitY = 0;
        int carrotCounter = 0;
        // Game Loop:
        while (true)
        {
            DrawLabyrinth(mapHeight, mapSize, charMap);
            MoveRabbit(mapHeight, mapSize, ref rabbitX, ref rabbitY, charMap);
            EatCarrot(rabbitX, rabbitY, charMap,carrotCounter);
            Console.SetCursorPosition(rabbitX, rabbitY);
            Console.Write(rabbitIcon);
            Thread.Sleep(66);
            Console.CursorVisible = false;
            Console.Clear();

        }
    }
    static void EatCarrot(int rabbitX, int rabbitY, char[,] theMap,int carrotCount)
    {
        if (theMap[rabbitY, rabbitX] == '7' || theMap[rabbitY, rabbitX] == '8')
        {
            if (theMap[rabbitY, rabbitX] == '7')
            {
                theMap[rabbitY, rabbitX] = ' ';
                theMap[rabbitY - 1, rabbitX] = ' ';
                carrotCount++;

            }
            else if (theMap[rabbitY, rabbitX] == '8')
            {
                theMap[rabbitY, rabbitX] = ' ';
                theMap[rabbitY + 1, rabbitX] = ' ';
                carrotCount++;
            }
        }

    }

    static void MoveRabbit(int height, int width, ref int rabbitX, ref int rabbitY, char[,] theMap)
    {
        if (Console.KeyAvailable == true)
        {
            ConsoleKeyInfo pressedKey = Console.ReadKey(true);
            while (Console.KeyAvailable) Console.ReadKey(true);
            if (pressedKey.Key == ConsoleKey.LeftArrow || pressedKey.Key == ConsoleKey.A)
            {
                if (theMap[rabbitY, rabbitX - 1] == ' ' || theMap[rabbitY,rabbitX - 1 ] == '7' || theMap[rabbitY,rabbitX - 1 ] == '8')
                {
                    rabbitX -= 1;
                }
            }
            else if (pressedKey.Key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow || pressedKey.Key == ConsoleKey.D)
            {
                if (theMap[rabbitY, rabbitX + 1] == ' ' || theMap[rabbitY,rabbitX + 1 ] == '7' || theMap[rabbitY,rabbitX + 1 ] == '8')
                {
                    rabbitX += 1; 
                }
            }
            else if (pressedKey.Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow || pressedKey.Key == ConsoleKey.W)
            {
                if (theMap[rabbitY - 1, rabbitX] == ' ' || theMap[rabbitY - 1,rabbitX ] == '7' || theMap[rabbitY - 1,rabbitX ] == '8')
                {
                    rabbitY -= 1;
                }
            }
            else if (pressedKey.Key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow || pressedKey.Key == ConsoleKey.S)
            {
                if (theMap[rabbitY + 1, rabbitX] == ' ' || theMap[rabbitY + 1, rabbitX] == '7' || theMap[rabbitY + 1, rabbitX] == '8')
                {
                    rabbitY += 1;

                }
            }
        }
    }
    static void DrawLabyrinth(int height, int width, char[,] array)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
            {
                if (array[i, j] == '1')
                    Console.Write("─");
                else if (array[i, j] == '2')
                    Console.Write("│");
                else if (array[i, j] == '3')
                    Console.Write("┌");
                else if (array[i, j] == '4')
                    Console.Write("┐");
                else if (array[i, j] == '5')
                    Console.Write("└");
                else if (array[i, j] == '6')
                    Console.Write("┘");
                else if (array[i, j] == '7')
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.Write("▼");
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                }
                else if (array[i, j] == '8')
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    Console.Write("\u00B8");
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                }
                else if (array[i, j] == '9')
                {
                    Console.Write("┬");
                }
                else if (array[i, j] == '0')
                {
                    Console.Write("┴");
                }
                else if (array[i, j] == 'a')
                {
                    Console.Write('├');
                }
                else if (array[i, j] == 'b')
                {
                    Console.Write('┤');
                }
                else if (array[i, j] == 'c')
                {
                    Console.Write('┼');
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write(" ");
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Generally one does not clear background when painting over complete canvas... Try removing `.Clear` call and instead just position cursor.

Comment: Console output is slow.  You *must* get rid of Console.Clear() and write code that only updates the character positions that changed, grouping them as much as possible.

Answer (score 4):

The biggest problem with your code is the fact that you are continuously refreshing the screen, **even if there is no need to redraw anything** because the user has not moved the rabbit.

As indicated, what you want to do is the minimum amount of redrawing, i.e. only redraw when there is something to redraw, and then try to do the minimum possible amount. For your example game, in pseudo code this should look something like this:

```
// One time actions
var maze = ReadMaze(level);
DrawMaze(maze);
DrawRabbit(rabbitX, rabbitY);

// Game loop
while ((var input = GetInput()) != Input.Quit) {
    oldRabbitX = rabbitX, oldRabbitY = rabbitY;
    if (MoveRabbit(input, rabbitX, rabbitY, maze)) {
        EraseRabbit(oldX, oldY);
        DrawRabbit(rabbitX, rabbitY);
        if (IsPositionWithCarrot(rabbitX, rabbitY, maze))
            // This only the erases the carrot on screen.
            EatCarrot(rabbitX, rabbitY, maze);
    }
}
```

A blog post with a lot of useful information on building a c# console game can be found [here](http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2010/08/understanding-c-text-mode-games.html).

Because I found this to be a fun problem, I took your code and reshaped it a little bit to match the pseudo code above. This removes all flickering from the game. You can find this attempt below:

```
public class Game
{
    const string RabbitIcon = "\u0150";   //  \u0150   \u014E    \u00D2     \u00D3 --> alternatives
    static readonly char[] MazeChars = { '─', '│', '┌', '┐', '└', '┘', '▼', '\u00B8', '┬', '┴', '├', '┤', '┼' };
    static readonly ConsoleColor MazeFgColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGray;

    enum Input
    {
        MoveLeft,
        MoveRight,
        MoveUp,
        MoveDown,
        Quit
    };

    public static void Run()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Select Level (Available levels: 1,2):");
        Console.WriteLine("\n(\\_/)\n(o.o)\n(___)0\n");
        int carrotCounter = 0;
        int gameLevel = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // by pressing a number the user can select different labyrinths.

        // Console Height and Width
        Console.WindowHeight = 25;
        Console.BufferHeight = Console.WindowHeight + 1; // +1 to allow writing last character in the screen corner
        Console.BufferWidth = Console.WindowWidth = 80;
        Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;  // Must have this + Change font to Lucida in CMD

        // Reads maze map
        string[] mapRows = File.ReadAllLines(String.Format("game.level{0}.txt", gameLevel));
        if (!mapRows.All(r => r.Length == mapRows[0].Length))
            throw new InvalidDataException("Invalid map");
        var charMap = mapRows.Select(r => r.ToCharArray()).ToArray();

        // Draw maze & rabbit once 
        Console.CursorVisible = false;
        DrawLabyrinth(charMap);
        int rabbitX = 1, rabbitY = 1;
        DrawRabbit(rabbitX, rabbitY, RabbitIcon);

        // Game Loop:
        Input input;
        while ((input = GetInput()) != Input.Quit)
        {
            if (MoveRabbit(input, ref rabbitX, ref rabbitY, charMap) &&
                IsPositionWithCarrot(rabbitX, rabbitY, charMap))
                EatCarrot(rabbitX, rabbitY, charMap, ref carrotCounter);
        }
    }

    static void EatCarrot(int rabbitX, int rabbitY, char[][] theMap, ref int carrotCounter)
    {
        // determine carrot top position.
        var carrotTopY = theMap[rabbitY][rabbitX] == '7' ? rabbitY - 1 : rabbitY;
        // "eat it" from the map.
        theMap[carrotTopY][rabbitX] = ' ';
        theMap[carrotTopY + 1][rabbitX] = ' ';
        // and erase it on screen;
        Console.SetCursorPosition(rabbitX, carrotTopY);
        Console.Write(' ');
        Console.SetCursorPosition(rabbitX, carrotTopY + 1);
        Console.Write(' ');
        // redraw the rabbit
        carrotCounter++;
        DrawRabbit(rabbitX, rabbitY, RabbitIcon);
    }

    static Input GetInput()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var key = Console.ReadKey(true);
            switch (key.Key)
            {
                case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
                case ConsoleKey.A:
                    return Input.MoveLeft;
                case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
                case ConsoleKey.D:
                    return Input.MoveRight;
                case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
                case ConsoleKey.W:
                    return Input.MoveUp;
                case ConsoleKey.DownArrow: 
                case ConsoleKey.S:
                    return Input.MoveDown;
                case ConsoleKey.Q:
                    return Input.Quit;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    static bool IsValidRabbitPosition(int x, int y, char[][] theMap)
    {
        return x >= 0 && x < theMap[0].Length && y >= 0 && y < theMap.Length &&
               (theMap[y][x] == ' ' || IsPositionWithCarrot(x, y, theMap));
    }

    static bool IsPositionWithCarrot(int x, int y, char[][] theMap)
    {
        return theMap[y][x] == '7' || theMap[y][x] == '8';
    }

    static void DrawRabbit(int x, int y, string rabbitIcon)
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkYellow;
        Console.Write(rabbitIcon);
        Console.ResetColor();
    }

    static bool MoveRabbit(Input direction, ref int rabbitX, ref int rabbitY, char[][] theMap)
    {
        int newX = rabbitX, newY = rabbitY;
        switch (direction)
        {
            case Input.MoveLeft: newX--; break;
            case Input.MoveRight: newX++; break;
            case Input.MoveUp: newY--; break;
            case Input.MoveDown: newY++; break;
            default: return false;
        }
        if (IsValidRabbitPosition(newX, newY, theMap))
        {
            DrawRabbit(rabbitX, rabbitY, " "); // erase
            rabbitX = newX;
            rabbitY = newY;
            DrawRabbit(rabbitX, rabbitY, RabbitIcon); // draw
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    static void DrawLabyrinth(char[][] theMap)
    {
        Console.Clear();
        for (int y = 0; y < theMap.Length; y++)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, y);
            for (int x = 0; x < theMap[0].Length; x++)
            {
                var ndx = theMap[y][x] - '1';
                var c = ndx >= 0 && ndx < MazeChars.Length 
                    ? MazeChars[ndx] 
                    : ' ';

                Console.ForegroundColor = IsPositionWithCarrot(x, y, theMap)
                    ? ndx == 6 ? ConsoleColor.Red : ConsoleColor.Green
                    : MazeFgColor;

                Console.Write(c);
                Console.ResetColor();
            }
        }
        Console.WindowTop = 0; // scroll back up.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the (many) reasons a console application isn't a good choice for a real-time game (or really, any other animation). As you have shown, you can definitely do it, but constantly clearing and redrawing the *entire window* is going to flicker.

So the real solution is to pick a technology that is better with animation, such as Windows Forms or even better, WPF. Both can move an element across the screen and only redraw the "dirty" areas, which is a *huge* capability in terms of reducing flicker.

If you are intent on doing this in a console application, I would do your own "dirty" checking by moving the console cursor around, erasing your old position and redrawing the character at the new one. It still won't be as efficient as a true graphics library, and your character may still flicker if it has a significant size, but it will be a *ton* better.

Comment: True, but for simple console games using good buffer management & invalidation (e.g. with `Console.MoveBufferArea`) you can make it perform well enough. And console games are fun in that nostalgic way.

Comment: Please reflect on whether it's a good idea to advise WPF as a better GUI technology for a *first project*. The qualities that WPF has are almost certainly not the qualities that a beginner will need or appreciate.

Comment: @Alex Sure, you can do it, its just not the best for a game

Comment: @zneak and Casey, I realize that neither WinForms or WPF are good for a game, but I'm not sure trying to go yet another level to something like XNA or Unity is a good idea. Additionally I will continue to hold that game programming in *general* doesn't make a good first project due to the complexities involved, so the fact that it requires a more complex framework is really already a given.

Comment: That's a bold statement. The maze program fits within 200 lines of C#. And then what about hangman? What about minesweeper? What about battleship, tic-tac-toe? Games existed long before we had access to any complex framework to make them. OP only wants a bitmap plane, and a console window is a perfectly fine starting point for that.

Comment: @zneak Say its bold if you like, but I truly believe that games, especially of any complexity, are a *terrible* choice for a first project, as they require an understanding of design, data structures, and often some design patterns to do correctly. I will agree that simple games such as those you mentioned certainly can be done in a console application, of course, they usually don't require animation (notice I specified that and not "any games", in my answer). That said, one of the reasons we have the complex frameworks is to make graphics like this much easier, as console *sucked*.